# How to access the structures from testbench

Tags: system-verilog

```
typedef struct packed signed{
    bit valid;
    bit tag;
    bit signed[31:0] data;
}my_data;

module structure_example5(input clk,input my_data a);

always@(posedge clk) begin
    if(a.tag>a.valid)begin
      $display("G");
    end
    else begin
      $display("L");
    end
  end

endmodule:structure_example5

//TEST BENCH

module structure_example5_tb;

reg clk;
  reg a.tag,a.valid;  

  structure_example5 uut (clk,a);

  initial begin
   #5 
   clk=0;
   forever
     #5clk=!clk;
  end

  initial begin
    a.tag=1'b1;
    a.valid=1'b0;
    #50
    $finish();
  end 
endmodule:structure_example5_tb
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until and unless struct is of single direction there won't be any difficulty in connecting test-bench and DUT ports together

Here at your test-bench code comment out reg declaration of structure members and use structure declaration

```
//reg a.tag,a.valid;  
my_data a;
```

and try to run your code, the corrected/working code can be found in the [link](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/73p)

**UPDATE:**

As per Dave's suggestion, it is recommended that when sharing typedefs with multiple modules using a package is the better solution, to use, define all your typedefs inside the package and import the package in the required module, it can be any module including testbench and DUT.

eg:

```
package my_pkg;    
typedef struct packed signed{
          bit valid;
          bit tag;
          bit signed[31:0] data;
      }my_data;
endpackage
```

and whenever you require content of package inside your module use

```
import my_pkg::*;
```

Also updated the link mentioned above with package

Comment: I strongly suggest defining your `typedef`s in a common package and importing that package when sharing types across multiple modules. See http://go.mentor.com/package-import-versus-include

Comment: I totally agree with you @dave_59, since it was a single tb I just took it directly from compilation unit, After going through the article I noted that it may cause incompatible types, so updated the answer and really enjoyed the precise description about package in the article "Importing a name from a package does not duplicate text; it makes that name visible from another package without copying the definition"